# How many $7$ digit numbers can be formed using $0,1,1,2,2,2,3$?

Tags: combinatorics

I understand that we can't use 0 for the first digit.
I've solved forming 8 digit number using 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3. We have 8 digits: two 1, three 2 and three 3. First I put three 2s in 8 possible places. Number of putting 2s =  $8!/(3!*5!)$. After putting 2s we have 5 possible empty places left. We put three 3s = $5!/(3!*2!)$. Then we have 2 empty places and two 1s = $2!/(0!*2!)$. The answer will be multiplication of all these. Is this right or I have wrote something wrong? And how to write for having $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic procedure is correct. Use the same method. There are $\binom{6}{1}$ ways to place the $0$. For each of these there are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to place the $2$'s. Continue. The number of ways is indeed the product.